Can Objective Bayesian Epistemology and religious belief be reconciled?
From Bayesian epistemology (SEP):

Bayesian Epistemology
First published Mon Jun 13, 2022
We can think of belief as an all-or-nothing affair. For example, I believe that I am alive, and I don’t believe that I am a historian of the Mongol Empire. However, often we want to make distinctions between how strongly we believe or disbelieve something. I strongly believe that I am alive, am fairly confident that I will stay alive until my next conference presentation, less confident that the presentation will go well, and strongly disbelieve that its topic will concern the rise and fall of the Mongol Empire. The idea that beliefs can come in different strengths is a central idea behind Bayesian epistemology. Such strengths are called degrees of belief, or credences. Bayesian epistemologists study norms governing degrees of beliefs, including how one’s degrees of belief ought to change in response to a varying body of evidence. Bayesian epistemology has a long history. Some of its core ideas can be identified in Bayes’ (1763) seminal paper in statistics (Earman 1992: ch. 1), with applications that are now very influential in many areas of philosophy and of science.
[...]
4.2 Objective Bayesianism
Objective Bayesians contend that, in addition to coherence, there is another epistemic virtue or ideal that needs to be codified into a norm for prior credences: freedom from bias and avoidance of overly strong opinions (Jeffreys 1939; Carnap 1945; Jaynes 1957, 1968; Rosenkrantz 1981; J. Williamson 2010). This view is often motivated by a case like this:

Example (Six-Faced Die). Suppose that there is a cubic die with six faces that look symmetric, and we are going to toss it. Suppose further that we have no other idea about this die. Now, what should our credence be that the die will come up 6?

An intuitive answer is 1/6, for it seems that we ought to distribute our credences evenly, with an equal credence, 1/6, in each of the six possible outcomes. While subjective Bayesians would only say that we may do so, objective Bayesians would make the stronger claim that we ought to do so. More generally, objective Bayesians are sympathetic to this norm:

The Principle of Indifference. A person’s credences in any two propositions should be equal if her total evidence no more supports one than the other (the evidential symmetry version), or if she has no sufficient reason to have a higher credence in one than in the other (the insufficient reason version).


Consider a person who subscribes to Objective Bayesianism. According to the principles outlined above, such a person would aim to eliminate bias and overly strong opinions from their priors. They would also adhere to the principle of indifference, assigning equal credence to propositions in the absence of reasons or asymmetries in the evidence to justify favoring one over another. Within these epistemological constraints, does religious belief (e.g., in God, miracles, ghosts, the supernatural, the paranormal, an afterlife, reincarnation, karma, New Age beliefs, etc.) become entirely untenable, or could an objective Bayesian still justify holding such beliefs?
Has anyone attempted to reconcile Objective Bayesianism with religious belief in the literature?

Preemptive rebuttal to close-votes
Since clove-voters have not yet provided arguments to rebut in the comment section, this preemptive rebuttal will focus on appealing to the inconsistency of close-voters. Concretely, I invite close-voters to be consistent by voting to close the following related questions as well:

How can religious faith be epistemically justified? (71 upvotes, 41 answers)
Is faith an epistemology? (10 upvotes, 7 answers)
Has anyone ever argued that religious beliefs are unjustified true beliefs? (6 upvotes, 5 answers)
Can science or history be used to examine religions claims despite it being a naturalist enterprise that denies the existence of the supernatural? (6 upvotes, 4 answers)
Does the demand for evidence run contrary to faith? (4 upvotes, 3 answers)
Are some religious claims subject to empirical testing? (2 upvotes, 1 answer)
A critique of the epistemoloical models of religion (2 upvotes, 1 answer)


Once you've eliminated the overly strong opinions, whatever remains, however indifferent, must be the Truth.

Most of those questions were asked over five years ago. Nobody's going to go back and close questions from five years ago, because nobody really answers or comments on questions that old. Plus, the rules on the stack can change - it'd be unfair to close a question that was asked in full compliance with the rules of that time. The reason for post closure can be seen in the banner; we shouldn't need to comment to identify why your post was closed. If the question is well-asked and in compliance with the stack (which you're surely good at doing given your rep), no rebuttal should be needed.

@controlgroup "The reason for post closure can be seen in the banner; we shouldn't need to comment to identify why your post was closed." - The two close-votes cast so far provide the following common reason: This question doesn’t meet a Philosophy Stack Exchange guideline.  The What topics can I ask about here? article isn't very helpful in clarifying the closure reason either. My question matches both epistemology and applied philosophy (my question is asking to apply Bayesian epistemology to philosophy of religion).

Which guidelines do the votes indicate that this post does not meet? That doesn't mean that the tags are wrong, it means that there's a specific rule like not pushing personal philosophies being violated.

@controlgroup Unfortunately the close-voters didn't clarify that. The close pop-up window only shows 2 votes cast for A community-specific reason This question doesn’t meet a Philosophy Stack Exchange guideline., without being specific about which guideline. Additional feedback via comments from the close-voters would help a lot.

Well, if the post gets closed, that additional reason will necessarily show up. If it doesn't, then congrats, your post won't be closed. No scenario here necessitates immediate rebuttals like that, and that's not so much of a rebuttal as a list of related questions from a long time ago. It's also generally assumed that with someone of your rep (that's a minimum of over ~300 upvotes you've got!) that posts should be roughly consistent with the rules at this point so less feedback would be provided (which sucks, yeah, but that's how it is).

@controlgroup And yet, I have no clue as to what guideline my question is violating. Close-voters, please provide feedback via comments.

@controlgroup This is very intriguing. Check out this question of mine asked 1 month ago (not 5 years ago, thus invalidating your 5-year objection). No close-votes. What's going on?

The basis of religious belief seems inherently biased, so I don't know how one would get to 'objective' from there. By not caring about the results? The whole point, is that it's about extremely important things. Otherwise, people wouldn't have been hunting this down for millenia. But what if it is an artifact of human psychology? Then I suppose, Subjective Bayesianism might be better. Jesus said you should love him more than your family, so "degrees of belief" appears to be ruled out.

Gee, this went off the boil in a hurry. I was thinking that the Ouroboros of theism requiring permissivism would be self-contradictory enough to get some attention, and likely drive a stake through it, but oh well.

It is not really an issue of compatibility. It is possible to apply Bayesian methods to issues of religious belief such as whether there are gods. Richard Swinburne (The Existence of God, 2nd edition, 2004) made an attempt to do so.
The difficulty is that it is highly problematic to decide what counts as an application of the principle of indifference. Swinburne assumes that the prior probability that a god exists is 0.5. But why should we suppose that? There are lots of different gods that people believe in. We have no firm grasp of the space of alternative hypotheses and how it is structured.
Also, there is no clear source for the conditional probabilities. We cannot observe what the universe would be like if there were gods and if there were not. It is not easy to devise experiments that have different results depending on whether gods exist or not. And even if we managed to do so, there will always be difficulties in interpreting the results.
More generally, the principle of indifference is not straightforward to apply at the best of times. It is not a law of probability. It is more like a heuristic that works well in some situations, but is almost impossible to apply in others. I wrote some more about indifference in my answer to this question.
As a footnote, not all Bayesians favour the objective approach. Subjective Bayesians do not accept that there are such things as objective priors. Your priors just are whatever degree of credence you happen to have. Some go further and say it is irrational to erase your priors and replace them with 'objective' ones, because doing so is a violation of Bayesian conditioning.

The complete lack of information about a particular hypothesis if it stems from a lack of evidence (say, god) should result in a very small prior. Anything else seems unreasonable, and there’s a simple thought experiment that can demonstrate this. If god or the supernatural was present and visible everywhere and actually verifiably did things with an observed frequency that everyone could verify, but in a very infrequent way, the prior probability of the supernatural would be low. But if it’s not observed at all, it makes no sense to assign the prior anything higher than that.

Objective Bayesianism doesn’t say that you need to have an objective well defined and agreed upon prior before making a belief tenable. It just means that apart from making sure that your priors are coherent, they should also be free of bias as much as possible. If an objective bayesian can rationalize a prior like this and then use evidence from the world to increase that prior and get a high enough posterior probability for theism then their belief becomes tenable.
The problem of course is that the very notion of freedom from bias is very ill defined and eons have been spent debating whether or not supernatural belief stems from a lack of evidence and bias to religious upbringing vs. being based upon legitimate evidence.
